# PHP/Codeigniter - MySQL error on fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, full-text-search, boolean

I'm trying to perform a fulltext search with codeigniters built in Active Record methods. I had a "custom" query string before that i pretty much copied into codeigniter code (so to speak). Somewhere in the where statement there's an error, but i can't find it.

```
$this->db->select('movies.*');
$this->db->from('movies');
$this->db->join('movies_genres', 'movies.id = movies_genres.movie_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('genres', 'movies_genres.genre_id = genres.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('MATCH (movies.movie_title) AGAINST (`'.$query.'`) IN BOOLEAN MODE', null, false);
//$this->db->group_by('movies.id');
//$this->db->limit($count, $page);
```

By default codeigniter helps out by adding backticks around variables to make them more secure. I tried  turning that off as well by setting the last param to false, but still no luck. By commenting out the last two lines i still got the same error, and if i comment out the where statement, the error disappears (and i get results).

Here is the query generated by Codeigniter:

```
SELECT `movies`.* FROM (`movies`) LEFT JOIN `movies_genres` ON `movies`.`id` = `movies_genres`.`movie_id` LEFT JOIN `genres` ON `movies_genres`.`genre_id` = `genres`.`id` WHERE MATCH (movies.movie_title) AGAINST (`the`) IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

And here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BOOLEAN MODE' at line 5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 AGAINST (`'.$query.'`)
```

shouldn't be with backticks, but with quotes. try

```
AGAINST (\''.$query.'\')
```

also, the syntax seems to be

```
AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

if I read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html correctly

Comment: I doubt that, at least the error should have the change in backtick/quote represented?

Comment: Well yea, the qoutes are now sigle qoutes instead of backticks. That's the only difference i see. Other than that it's all the same.

Comment: You might want to read the manual btw. I just did, and found that the syntax is like so: `AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I'm aware of the syntax. If no operator (+ or -) is used before the word, it implies as "or". The syntax seems right, it's just not working. Even by putting a + before the $query, it still doesn't work, so i don't think that's the problem.

Comment: My bad, had the last parenthesis in the wrong place. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally put the last ending parenthesis in the wrong place. It should be after "BOOLEAN MODE", not after the search string where i put it.

$this->db->where("MATCH (movies.movie_title) AGAINST ('+".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", null, false);